# Use WebBrowserControl Capture Form Post

Tags: c#, .net, http, webbrowser-control

I am working on an Html/Http inspection UI for a specialized system. I am wondering if someone knows how to capture the values of a POST generated inside of a WebBrowserControl from code to trap what values were posted and the location(action) of the post. I am not looking for a tool as Fiddler and Firebug's Net panel both do this beautifully, I am looking for a way to capture and record posts in code from .Net using the WebBrowserControl. Is there a way to do this?

Note: My current version of this tool reads and inspects forms/values present on the HTMLDocument, but it is not sufficient since often forms can be dynamically submitted via script and have the action/form values altered, or submit to a different hidden or dynamically created form.

I am open to having an in process http inspection library/code/proxy in place if that is the only way to do this. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. This post http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/eab43afa-df4d-4278-926a-b07d2d6ca9fd/ led me to an extended implementation of the WebBrowser control on [codeproject here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/ExtendedWebBrowser.aspx) which wraps the WebBrowserControl and exposes the extended DWebBrowserEvents2 event data which contains the postData and headers pre-navigation so that you can capture them. I did have to extend that example's implementation of BrowserExtendedNavigatingEventArgs to handle postData and headers but that was trivial.

Hopefully this helps someone else out.

Comment: Hi, can you show us how you modified the code to send header and post data? Thanks.