# WebBrowser control get form action

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, webbrowser-control

I have a Windows Form with a WebBrowser control in it. I'm going to a page and I want the action of the form on that page.

SO when the HTML of the page looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <title>testing</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="http://www.testing.nl/form.php?hoi=true" >

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to receive `http://www.testing.nl/form.php?hoi=true` in C#. How can I do that?

**-note-** The URL is fake, just to show what i want...

Comment: The link says: `Page not found`. What are you trying to do. Its not clear

Comment: The url of the action is what i need to process some data. So i need an way to get the url of the action of the form, to an string in C# (hope that this was clear enough)

Comment: An answer to your question (which has already been asked on SO) can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423395/use-webbrowsercontrol-capture-form-post

Comment: So you mean you want to capture the url of the page to which your browser navigated in a string. Right?

Comment: No, because i don't want to trigger the form (so it post), but i just want to get the action URL....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will go through all the forms in the webpage and extract the `action` attribute for each one:

```
var actions = new List<string>();
if (webBrowser1.Document != null)
{
    actions.AddRange(from HtmlElement form in webBrowser1.Document.Forms select form.GetAttribute("action"));
}
```

You have to make sure that the page is fully loaded.